# Array to object with Array.reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of key-value pairs:

```
const arr = [
  { key: 'One', value: '1' },
  { key: 'Two', value: '2' },
  { key: 'Three', value: '3' }
];
```

I would like to convert the above array into this kind of object:

```
const obj = {
  'One': '1',
  'Two': '2',
  'Three': '3'
}
```

by using the `Array.reduce()` function.
This is what have I done so far:

```
const obj = arr.reduce( (prev, curr) => prev[curr.key] = curr.value, {} );
```

which is not working because, on the second run of the `reduce` function, `prev` is *undefined* and therefore I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'Two' of undefined
```

I thought I would be able to compose `obj` at each `reduce` iteration...
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You choose the right function, however, the only missing part was the value returned for each item was not the accumulator (object in our case). Ensuring this will fix your problem.

```js
const arr = [{ key: 'One', value: '1' },{ key: 'Two', value: '2' },{ key: 'Three', value: '3' }];

const obj = arr.reduce( (prev, curr) => {
  prev[curr.key] = curr.value;
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Object.assign` inside the reduce method.

```js
const arr = [{ key: 'One', value: '1' },{ key: 'Two', value: '2' },{ key: 'Three', value: '3' }];
const obj = arr.reduce( (prev, {key, value}) => Object.assign(prev, {[key]: value}), {} );
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) the the object to get the `key` and the `value` properties. Then use [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals), and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) to add the key and value to the `prev` object:

```js
const arr = [
  { key: 'One', value: '1' },
  { key: 'Two', value: '2' },
  { key: 'Three', value: '3' }
];

const obj = arr.reduce( (prev, { key, value }) => ({ ...prev, [key]: value }), {});

console.log(obj);
```

Another option is to use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and convert each object to this form - { [key]: value }. Then merge everything by spreading into [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const arr = [
  { key: 'One', value: '1' },
  { key: 'Two', value: '2' },
  { key: 'Three', value: '3' }
];

const obj = Object.assign(...arr.map(({ key, value }) => ({ [key]: value })));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Lots of unnecessary temporary objects there, though (in both cases).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - functional programming at it's best.

Comment: @OriDrori - For some definition of "best." :-)

Comment: @trincot actually you were first ... a long time ago ...

Answer (score 2):

You got `undefined` because `prev` doesn't have the attribute in `prev[curr.key]`.

Here is my solution:

```js
const arr = [
  { key: 'One', value: '1' },
  { key: 'Two', value: '2' },
  { key: 'Three', value: '3' }
];

const result = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  return {
    ...prev,
    [curr.key]: curr.value
  }
}, {});

console.log(result);
```